# Is there a pre-built LAMP server image for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: image

I'm looking to set up a simple LAMP server. I do know how do this manually. I ***am not*** looking for a guide as to how to setup a LAMP server. Is there a pre-built LAMP server image that already has PHP, MYSQL, Apache, etc., already installed? I'd like to skip the manual CLI install work.

Comment: I know this will not answer your question but if you have access to an Ubuntu server platform you can just: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^. Otherwise I would say that install each LAMP component from the command line is not that hard. Really.

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks. Good thing to know. However for this specific use case, I need an image.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you not just install a base image of Rasbian, then manually install the LAMP server packages, and then make an image of that for later use?

Comment: @leonardo Yep, but I'd like to not have to mess around with configuring the settings for the LAMP server.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this pre-made SD image for a lamp stack: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=37297 - planning on trying it myself soon!

Comment: I couldn't get the .zip file to work right. It won't expand correctly. Thoughts? (OS X 10.8.3)

Comment: i'm on a terrible internet connection, so not able to download the zip and try it myself. Just done a little dig around, and looks like this may be a more up-to-date version of the image: http://www.lampi.co.uk/downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for an image to perform multiple installations later, that could be easily made:

1. download raspbian
2. copy image to SD
3. boot your Pi
4. install LAMP
5. shutdown
6. create an image from SD
7. PROFIT!?

Comment: Yep, essentially my comment above. However, user wants a pre-made image.

Comment: @leonardo i'm pretty sure this is what he will do in the end =)